# Android datepicker automatic changes in year and month fields

Tags: android, datepicker

The default DatePicker in android changes the year when i switch the month from january to december by scrolling it up(And does this, when switching days, too). Its really annoying, and confusing, i want to disable this function, but i cant find any methods or xml attributes to do this.

So basically what i need to achieve is when you scroll through months or days, the year (and/or month) filelds shouldn't be affected.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create the following attributes in the class:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
private int oldYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
private int oldMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
private int oldDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Then overwrite the onDateChanged method:

```
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        if (oldDay != day) {
            if (oldMonth != month) {
                month = oldMonth;
            }
            oldDay = day;
        }
        if (oldMonth != month) {
            if (oldYear != year) {
                year = oldYear;
            }
            oldMonth = month;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code to **stop auto-scroll year** when we jump from **January to December** or **December to January**

```
val oldMonthOfYear = 0
val oldYear = 0

date_input.setOnDateChangedListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            if ((oldMonthOfYear == 0 && monthOfYear == 11) || (oldMonthOfYear == 11 && monthOfYear == 0)) {
                if (oldYear != year) {
                    date_input.updateDate(oldYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
                }
            } else {
                oldYear = year
            }
            oldMonthOfYear = monthOfYear
        }
```